# Form dropdown menu passing array as object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I'm trying to pass trough form dropdown selection but I can't pass array(the rest of the form is using objects. This is my code

Controller

```
$var->user = $request->users->id;
```

view

```
{!! Form::select('users', $users,null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a user']) !!}
```

One solution is converting array to object using eloquent, how can that be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get selected user's ID, I guess you need to do this:

```
$request->users
```

You're getting "Trying to get property of non-object" error, because `$request->users` is not an object.

Comment: but when sending form the error  "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood you. Please read updated answer. You can look what you get after form submitting with this clause `dd($request->all());`.

Comment: how to turn that into an object with eloquent

Comment: You mean turn string (ID) to an object? What kind of object do you want to get (and instance of a User model or something else)? Why do you want this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the user list you can follow this:

In Controller:

```
$user_id = UserModel::lists('username','id')->all();
```

"usename" and "id" is user-table fields.you can replace any other fields which you will show in user list.

In view:

```
{!! Form::select('user_id', $user_id,Input::old('user_id'),['placeholder'=>'select  user']) !!}
```